# Управление другим процессом из дискорд-бота

Tags: java, python, c++, процесс

У меня есть приложение на `Java`, являющееся **дискорд-ботом**. У меня есть игровой **сервер** Arma 3.
Мне нужно, что бы командой из дискорд бота можно было:

- **Выключать** процесс сервера
- Узнавать, **включен ли** он
- **Запускать** его.

Вопрос: Какой **самый простой** путь реализовать это?
*Да, меня не забанили в гугле, но я просто хочу увидеть советы от разных опытных людей конкретно в такой формулировке вопроса*

Список языков, один из которых я бы хотел использовать для этого (выше == релевантнее):

- `Python`, т.к. мне кажется, что на нем контроль процессов реализовать проще всего
- `Java`, т.к. это можно будет встроить прямо в бота, *но, как мне кажется, контролировать процессы там довольно геморно*
- `C++` *- а может, в нем это легче всего?*

*Если предложите решение **не на Java**, то уточните, как лучше осуществить коммуникацию между дискорд-ботом и этой программой*

Какие языки **не годятся**

- `shell` - годная вещь, но **машина на винде**
- `batch` - ненавижу его и не хочу разбираться
- `C#` - может быть на нем и будет просто, но я с ним не знаком

Comment: Не в тему, но понравилась формулировка *C++ - а может, в нем это легче всего?*. Даже призадумался, какую задачу можно решить на С++ легче, чем на любом другом языке... Разве что операции с памятью.

Comment: ну мало ли, там winapi какое-нибудь...

Comment: это ж в какой вселенной winapi был самым лёгким путём?